# Problem in Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a matrix $U$ such that

$U = 
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 &1&1\\
1 &o & o^2 &o^3 & o^4\\
1 & o^2 & o^4& o &o^3 \\
1 & o^3 & o& o^4 & o^2\\
1 & o^4 & o^3 &o^2 &o \\
\end{array}\right]$,
where $1+o+o^2+o^3+o^4=0$.

Prove that if $(i,j)$ entry $u_{ij}$ of $U$ is same as $(k,l)$ entry $u_{kl}$ of $U$, for any power $U^n$ of $U$ $(i,j)$th entry and $(k,l)$th entry will be same.

Comment: Is this an exercise from a book, or something like that?

Comment: Without doing the actual calculations (busy right now) - induction seems to be a good start.

Comment: This is the discrete Fourier transform matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) where each of your $o$'s are primitive roots of unity. Try searching for these keywords to get an idea of what's going on here.

Answer (score 2):

The second power $ U^2 $ is 5 times a permutation matrix $ P_{\pi} $, with the permutation specifically being, in one-line notation, $ \pi = ( 1 \, 5 \, 4 \, 3 \, 2 ) $. We know that the $ij$-entry of $ U $ is $ \sigma^{(i-1)(j-1)} $ by definition. You can make two small tables to check by brute force that $ (i-1)(j-1) \equiv (k - 1)(l-1) $ implies $ (\pi(i)-1) (\pi(j)-1) \equiv (\pi(k)-1)(\pi(l)-1) $ modulo 5. Hence if two entries of $ U $ are equal, their exponents in $ \sigma $ are equal, and therefore their exponents will be equal under any number of applications of $ \pi $ to the indices.

Comment: Like I said explicitly, I'm using one-line notation - not cycle notation. So according to what I've stated above, $ \pi(1) = 1 $, $ \pi(2) = 5 $, $ \pi(3) = 4 $, $ \pi(4) = 3 $, and $ \pi(5) = 2 $. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Notation. Note that the order is actually irrelevant because if congruence is invariant under one application of $ \pi $ then it is invariant under any number of applications.

Comment: I read one-line notation used as I use it somewhere or other years ago and it's been stuck in my brain ever since. My condolences to those who don't share my idiosyncrasy.

Comment: Thank you all for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Hint #1: Clearly $o\neq1$ (assuming that $o$ is a complex number), but 
$$0=(1-o)(1+o+o^2+o^3+o^4)=1-o^5,$$
so...

Hint #2: Start computing the powers of $U$. Use the result of the previous hint. Read the comment by M.B.